# How iOS's coordinate system works?

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, bounds

nice to meet you. I am studying "Coordinate System" of UIView of iOS.
Frame is easy to understand, but **Bounds** isn't.

For example, Frame works as expected when you change origin.
[image]

**Bounds does not change its position even if we change origin**.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var childView : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 200, height: 200)
        childView = UIView(frame: rect)
        childView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(childView)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {
            self.childView.bounds = CGRect(x: 100, y: 150, width: 200, height: 200)
        })
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

"Why do we need *Bounds*?" I thought. 
And I searched hard on the internet. So, there are some facts I found out.

----First----
 [image]

**Bounds literally means borderline.** iOS can draw a picture only within that boundary line. As you can see in the figure above, the UIButton also has Bounds, and when it exceeds the Bounds, the picture is cut and drawn.

---- Second ----
**Size of Bounds and Size of Frame are the same.**
[image]

It's not important, but I tried to test it out.

---- Thirds ----
*bounds.origin* is also useful in View Hierarchy. But it works differently from Frame.

Frame is easy to understand.
The *ViewController's RootView* will be 700 from top to button.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var childView : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let rect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
        childView = UIView(frame: rect)
        childView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(childView)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {

        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 700, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

        })
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

If you look at the Coordinate System in iOS, you can see that Frame should work like that.
 [image]

However, *Bounds* does not move itself, but only the *Subview* below it. I do not understand this part.
[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var childView : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let rect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
        childView = UIView(frame: rect)
        childView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(childView)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {

        self.view.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 700, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

        })
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

So, I searched it in google.
Eventually, I found a mathematical formula for "SubView" to reposition when *SuperView.origin.bounds* was changed.
( 출처 : [article](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/scroll-view/) )

```
CompositedPosition.x = View.frame.origin.x - Superview.bounds.origin.x;
CompositedPosition.y = View.frame.origin.y - Superview.bounds.origin.y;
```

By the way, why did Apple use these formulas? Basically, based on the "Coordinate System" we think,

```
CompositedPosition.x = View.frame.origin.x + Superview.bounds.origin.x;
CompositedPosition.y = View.frame.origin.y + Superview.bounds.origin.y;
```

Is not this formula more intuitive?

So, My Question are these.

1. When I increase *SuperView.bounds.origin.y* by 700 in its original state, why does *SubView* move up not moving down ???
2. Should I just accept the formula and memorize it?

**---------------------------------------------------------------**

**----------------------------Edit--1----------------------------**

Now I Got the concept of bounds by studying UIScrollView!

```
CompositedPosition.x = View.frame.origin.x - Superview.bounds.origin.x;
CompositedPosition.y = View.frame.origin.y - Superview.bounds.origin.y;
```

This is right.

This is a picture what I understand.
[image]

yes, I agree this picture looks dizzy sorry!

If I scroll **UP** the scrollview, and bounds.origin.y will increase and offset.y will increase and the subviews attached in scrollview's frame.origin.y will **not** change but, iOS calculate where the subviews to draw(CompositedPosition) by using that formula so! It looks like that the subviews goes **UP**!.

In brief, bounds change -> iOS calculate by using that formula -> draw!

Comment: 1. Use English. 2. goto 1 :)

Comment: This is an English language site, and your post needs to be written in English. There are far too many images as well. Code needs to be in text, properly formatted, where it is readable. If you feel the need to annotate it, use comments in the code. This post isn't going to be of any use to people behind a proxy or reading on a mobile device, and people with limited (and sometimes expensive) bandwidth are going to be saying really rude things about you.

Comment: As there's no Stack Overflow variant in Korean, this needs to be in one of Engish, Spanish, Russian or Portuguese and posted on the appropriate site.

Comment: Sorry!, Now I translate.

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Comment: Thank you for link!

Answer (score 1):

First, please post in English or another supported language.

Second I think I might have understand what you are going for and here is the general simple answer.

First there is a coordinate system for everything, but each view also has its own coordinated system. Each subview of a view is defined inside of the superviews coordinate system.

I would try and say more but I am purely going of the pictures. And also even in the post was in English, I have trouble believing this post is a minimal example of the presented problem

Comment: Thank you for your post!